# Best way to represent survival data

Tags: survival, dataset, reliability

I have a question regarding the best way to represent survival data to predict the reliability of bike parts.

I have the manufacturing date of each bike. At the manufacturing data the bike is equipped with equipment that sends when a part breaks down. I do not have information on when a bike is repaired and back on the road.

```
╔═════════╦══════╦════════════╗
║ Bike ID ║ Time ║ PartNumber ║
╠═════════╬══════╬════════════╣
║       1 ║   10 ║         10 ║
║       1 ║  100 ║        120 ║
║       1 ║  110 ║         10 ║
║       1 ║  120 ║          1 ║
║       2 ║    0 ║          1 ║
║       2 ║   10 ║          3 ║
║       3 ║   50 ║        120 ║
║       3 ║   60 ║        140 ║
║       3 ║   70 ║          3 ║
╚═════════╩══════╩════════════╝
```

I am interested in the following analyses:

1. Reliability of individual parts e.g. 10, 120;
2. Competing risk for a bike break down; and,
3. Prediction of what event will occur at a certain time.

I tend to use R.

Comment: Not really a competing risk model. Those assume that one event is a censoring process for the other evetns.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: If you die of cancer you cannot later die of heart failure.

Comment: But what if I am interested in knowing whether someone is more likely to die of cancer than heart failure.

Comment: The estimates of the rates of each will be biased. However, you may be able to rank the rates relative to each other.

Comment: Thanks @DWin could you maybe elaborate how I could do this?